# is there any way to make syslog in one row from json-format?

Tags: cakephp, syslog, cakephp-2.1

I am new in logs.
Is there any way to make syslog in one row?
It has json-format in info.log, but I need to make it more readable in syslog (for google cloud logging).
I use cakephp v2.1.
**How it looks now:**

```
[SYSLOG] : info: Array
[SYSLOG] : info: (
[SYSLOG] : info:     [Message] => Array
[SYSLOG] : info:         (
[SYSLOG] : info:             [user_id] => 1321
[SYSLOG] : info:             [ip] => 172.10.1.1
[SYSLOG] : info:             [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh.... etc) 
[SYSLOG] : info:         )
[SYSLOG] : info: 
[SYSLOG] : info: )
```

This is config from bootstrap.php

```
CakeLog::config('default', [
    'engine' => 'SyslogLog',
    'types' => array('info', 'error', 'warning'),
]);
```

**How I want to see it**

```
[SYSLOG] : info: Array([Message] => Array([user_id] => 1321[ip] => 172.10.1.1[user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh.... etc)))
```

Maybe are there some tools in Google Cloud Logging to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it just changing function that send it.

How it was:

```
$this->log($log, 'info');
```

How I changed:

```
$this->log(json_encode($log), 'info');
```

P.S. sometimes simple is the best solution